# What is the Oracle stream equivalent in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, stream, oracle11g

What is the Oracle stream equivalent in SQL Server 2008 R2? What entities it can stream (sequences, functions, user data types)? Is there something like a "streaming plan" to set/choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hhmm. No exact equivalent

It'd be one of more of [replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) or [mirroring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917680.aspx) or [Service broker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917680.aspx)